# NPV of changing array without loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance

I am trying to create an NPV function (or alternatively use the given NPV function) in Python using Pandas/Numpy. I will use this simple data to explain what I am trying to do:

Here is a dataframe:

```
Index   Array
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
5       0
6       0
```

and let the rate simply be 0.05. What I would like to calculate is the NPV for each index number. The inputs into the NPV function are the rate (0.05) and an array. For index 0, the array should be (2,3,4,5,0,0), for index 1, the array should be (3,4,5,0,0) and so on.

Using Excel it would look like so:
[NPV Calculations in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baXFz.png)

The Excel formula:
'=NPV($P$6,R7:$R$12)' where P6 is the rate (fixed), R7 is the first value in the array (variable based on the index), for calculating index 0's NPV and R12 is the last value in the array (fixed) i.e. 0.

Now when I use the premade NPV function in the financial numpy package, I cannot easily change the range, I think I would have to use a loop to change the range of the array. I have also tried to define a NPV function from scratch that changes the range, **but cannot seem to think of a way to do it without loops**. Some ideas/tips might be creating a rates column to select values based on a range, using the lambda for quicker loops etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Below is some code I made to run through the NPV. I am unable to optimize it without using a loop which is my challenge.

```
data = {
'Index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
'C1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
l=[]
for i in df['Index']:
   a=list(df['C1'].tail(6-i))
   l.append(npf.npv(0.05,[0] + a))
df['C2']=l
```

The outcome is correct but not optimized which is my issue, the outcome can be seen:

```
        Index   C1  C2
0   0   1   12.194713
1   1   2   10.804449
2   2   3   8.344671
3   3   4   4.761905
4   4   5   0.000000
5   5   0   0.000000
6   6   0   0.000000
```

Comment: MRE please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DarkKnight, what specifically should I MRE, I'm quite new to SO

Comment: @glenn please show us the code that you tried, with the input data, what is the expected outcome and what is the actual outcome. As mentioned in the Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE) guide, it's easier with text as opposed to pictures

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ClauSt, I have edited my post to show some code I made, hope it is better now.

Answer (score 0):

`npf NPV` is diferent with Excel formula. I am not sure what does the first number (cell R6 in Excel) mean. All formulas have never refered it. Anyway, I just keep it.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy_financial as npf
data = [1,2,3,4,5,0,0]
rate = 0.05
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': data})
r_window = len(data) - 1  
df['rwin'] = [df['data'][(i - r_window):].tolist() for i in range(len(df))]
df['NPV'] = df['rwin'].apply(lambda x: npf.npv(rate, [0] + x))
df.loc[df.index[-1], 'NPV'] = 0
print(df.drop(columns=['rwin']))
```

```
   data        NPV                                                                            
0     1  12.194713                                                                            
1     2  10.804449                                                                            
2     3   8.344671                                                                            
3     4   4.761905                                                                            
4     5   0.000000                                                                            
5     0   0.000000                                                                            
6     0   0.000000
```

Comment: Whilst this works, I'm trying to avoid using any for loops at all, so the `for i in range(len(df))]` is still using a for loop. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use [`scipy.linalg.toeplitz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html) as well as `numpy` and `pandas`, you can use numpy arrays to achieve this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz

# initial dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Index": {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6},
     "C1": {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 0, 6: 0}}
    )

discount_rate = 0.05


# array of flows
arr_flows = np.tril(np.tile(df.C1.values, (len(df), 1)).T, -1)

# array of discounting multipliers
arr_discounts = np.tril(toeplitz(df.Index.rpow(1 + discount_rate).rdiv(1).values))

# NPV
df["NPV"] = np.sum(np.multiply(arr_flows, arr_discounts), axis=0)
```

This creates a 2d array of flows and discounting multipliers from the initial dataframe columns.

I have used the `Index` column here to represent the years, so that if there is a missing year then this would be taken into account with the discount factors.